# Confusion about type level bools in base

Tags: haskell

`Base` contains a number of type families for type level boolean operations as seen here:

https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Data-Type-Bool.html

However, the links to `True` and `False` just refer to data constructors of `Bool`, not types themselves, so presumably they can't be used for type level operations, as they're values, not types.

Could someone explain what's happening here and where I can find the type level definitions?

Comment: Newer GHC versions support values at the type level.

Comment: https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/promotion.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> the links to `True` and `False` just refer to data constructors of `Bool`, not types themselves

That's right. In fact they are not types (what values would e.g. `True` have<sup>*</sup>)? They are still themselves just values, of type `Bool`. Only, that entire type has been “lifted” one level through the [`-XDataKinds` extension](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.4.1/docs/html/users_guide/kind-polymorphism-and-promotion.html), so `Bool` is now also a type-level type: aka a **kind**.

Traditionally in Haskell, we work mainly with a damn single kind: `*`, the kind of ordinary types<sup>†</sup>. This kind contains `Bool` and `String` and `IO ()` and `(Int -> Double) -> Char`... everything that actually has values<sup>‡</sup>. Plus the constructor-kinds, which are all of some form `* -> *` and contain things like `Maybe` or `[]` (when *not* applied to a contained-type argument).

With `DataKinds` now, we have a whole added arsenal of kinds: any type<sup>§</sup> you could use in runtime-Haskell code can now also be used as a kind in compile-time! All of these kinds contain exactly the values they also have on the runtime level. But those type-level values, such as the `False` and `True` you asked about, are *not* actually types, they just live in the type-level. But you can *build* actual `*` types from them, e.g. with something like

```
data CanContain :: Bool -> * -> * where
  Interesting :: a -> CanContain True a
  Boring :: CanContain False a
```

then a function with type `X -> CanContain True Y` must actually generate an `Y` value, but a function with type `X -> CanContain False Y` needs not.

---

<sup>*</sup><sub>No, the answer is not `True`. Though, then we could implement `type Bool = Either False True`, which would kinda make sense.</sub>

<sup>†</sup><sub>Arguably, that not a very good name in a language which otherwise parses `*` as an infix symbol. It will actually be changed in the future.</sub>

<sup>‡</sup><sub>It's not quite so simple: there are also unboxed kinds, but those are a bit of a technical detail.</sub>

<sup>§</sup><sub>As dfeuer remarks, not *all* types can be lifted right now (GHC-7.10), but simple ones such as `Bool` certainly can.</sub>

Comment: I think your last sentence in the first paragraph is misleading, since __`Bool`__ is promoted to a kind. `True` is only promoted to a type constructor, not to a kind on it's own, and both `True` and `False` are of kind `Bool` in this context.

Comment: For now, not all types can be promoted. That feature is coming in ... 8.0? 8.2? I don't really know.